# Module to show all articles with Tag and in a Category

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, tags

I am trying to make a module to bring back all articles in a category "holidays" that have a tag of "cuba"

All the examples I can find are tag clouds or getting tags for the current article.

Does anyone have any code or pointers to understanding the Tag tables so I could write the SQL. The end result is a travel site showing other holidays with tag x.

thanks

Comment: Now up to 1000 views on this question, I wonder if its worth me submitting a PR to the Joomla project to add this as a core module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some nice chap has already created a module that displays articles with a certain TAG so no hacking involved,

I suppose it would be simple (depending on your coding experience) to add a new parameter of CATEGORY to the module XML and alter the model to incorporate this new parameter as well to this and build your own custom module

[Custom module to pull in articles of a certain TAG](https://github.com/lasinducharith/joomla-tags-selected)

Comment: Thanks, I found that with a random google query on the getTagItemsQuery method after doing this question, I'd not seen it the weeks I'd been looking before.

Comment: If you get round to adding the category filter why not fork the project ;-) Good Luck

Comment: Just seen this in a search result - I forked this a while ago and tidied it up / added in some additional options. Not sure if it helps, but have a gander at https://github.com/muckypuddle/joomla-tags-selected if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily get all articles tagged with a tag, but not from a specific category, so you'd have to check for that in a step 2.

In JHelperTags (defined in libraries\cms\helper) there is a method

```
public function getTagItemsQuery( $tagId, $typesr = null, $includeChildren = false, $orderByOption = 'c.core_title', $orderDir = 'ASC', $anyOrAll = true, $languageFilter = 'all', $stateFilter = '0,1' )
```

Assuming you know the id of your tag, you'd call the function with

```
$tagsHelper = new JHelperTags;
$articles = $tagsHelper->getTagItemsQuery( $tagId, 'com_content.article', true, 'c.core_publish_up', 'DESC', true, 'all', '1' );
```

Then just filter articles you need.