# Changing layout of tag search in smart search results joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla-3.x, tags, smartsearch

If I search by tags in smart search module it lists all tags.If I click on the tag it lists artices with that tag.Instead if I search by tags is there anyway to directly list articles with that tags??Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a complete answer, but hopefully point you in the right direction with a couple of resources.

You can override the tag search results by copying this file:

```
/components/com_finder/views/search/tmpl/default_result.php
```

to

```
/templates/default_template/html/com_finder/search/default_tag.php
```

**(Notice the name change)**
(Read more here on [Smart Search overrides here](http://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_Smart_Search_results_page).)

But honestly I'm not sure exactly how to get this view to display all articles with the tag in the search query. [This answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/module-to-show-all-articles-with-tag-and-in-a-category/3619#3619) has a code to get articles with a certain tag:

```
$tagsHelper = new JHelperTags;
$articles = $tagsHelper->getTagItemsQuery( $tagId, 'com_content.article', true, 'c.core_publish_up', 'DESC', true, 'all', '1' );
```

There's also a module available to display articles with a certain tag, maybe you can extract some of the code from it: https://github.com/lasinducharith/joomla-tags-selected

You'll probably have to work a little to put everything together, but it should absolutely be possible.

Hope this helped a little :)

Comment: ..Thanks a lot..I will try working on it..:)